# How can i set array of strings in HttpParams?

Tags: angular

i need to send query params as the following

```
api-service.com/auctions?filterBidAwardStatus=Awarded&filterBidAwardStatus=Not%20awarded
```

i need do to this automatically

so when i have

```
let myObj = {
   arr: ['Awarded', 'Not awarded']
}


getAuctionBIds(myObj) {
      let params = new HttpParams();
      for(let item in queryParams) {
        params = params.append(item, queryParams[item]);
      }
      return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {params})
  }
```

i get only once setted my key - once, but i need twice like in first cse. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way

```js
 getAuctionBIds(myObj) {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    for (let item in myObj) {
      if (queryParams[item]) {
        if (queryParams[item] instanceof Array) {
          console.log(queryParams[item])
          queryParams[item].forEach((data) => {
            console.log(item)
            params = params.append(`${item.toString()}`, data);
          });
        } else {
          params = params.set(item.toString(), queryParams[item]);
        }
      }
    }
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', { params })
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).